# Proving that the shaded angles are equal.

Tags: geometry

Help with geometry problem

> Prove that the shaded angles are equal?   Given that $AB$ is parallel  to $ED$   and $D$ is on $BC$

[image: enter image desc$ription here]

My try follows

I try to construct a circle passing through points A,C,D  but how can I  prove that point E is also on this circle ?
[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: is BC parallel to AE?

Comment: Is $D$ any point on $BC?$

Comment: @Narasimham  yes it is

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. You want to show that $A,C,D,E$ lie on a circle. One way to do this is by showing that $\angle CAE=\angle CDE$. Since $A$ is a tangent point, you know that $\angle CAE=\angle ABC$. Using that $AB$ and $DE$ are parallel, you have $\angle ABC=\angle CDE$, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[image: GeomProb]

Angle at $B$ equals marked angle at $D$ ( alternate angles between parallels)

as well as

it equals angle at $A$(because  angle between tgt-chord equals to what is subtended in alternate segment)

So they are equal.

This makes $ CDAF$ concyclic and result follows, angles $ DAC,  DFC $ are equal as subtended in same segment.

EDIT1:

So you are referring to point $F$ but not $E$.